# Where should I ask a question about modding Minecraft?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, scope

I am currently developing a mod for the game Minecraft and ran into a little issue with it. Where can I ask a question for this? Is there a specialized site beside [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com)? Perhaps [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd say the correct site is [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

[Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) doesn't accept programming oriented questions.