# Where do I post about creating a resource pack for Minecraft (Bedrock edition)

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where do I post about creating a resource pack for *Minecraft* ([Bedrock edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minecraft#Development))?

The question I have is "What does the 'modules' part of the manifest.json file? The Minecraft wiki does not explain what it does."

This does not belong on modding Minecraft, because it is not modding. I am just creating a manifest.json file and then putting a bunch of images into a folder.

Comment: I assume you mean to ask, "*What does the 'modules' part of the manifest.json file **do***?", yes? Also, the correct tag is [[tag:site-recommendation]] instead of [[tag:scope]], and [[tag:support]] may be better than [[tag:discussion]]

Comment: I don't know what it "modules" manifest.json file is at all.

Comment: So did you mean to ask "*What **is** the 'modules' part of the manifest.json file?*"

Answer (score 5):

JSON = JavaScript object notation syntax. If you are editing a manifest.json file, in a broad sense, you are coding / programming. It's very likely that the details about how to write a manifest.json file be on the reference documentation for programmers / developers.

---

[Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) might be the more appropriate site. It has the tag [minecraft-modding](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-modding).

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) is for programming questions. It has some tags that are related to Minecraft:

- [minecraft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minecraft)
- [minecraft-forge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-forge)
- [minecraft-fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-fabric)

Take your time to review the tag excerpts / wikis and alias of the above tags. They might be helpful to write good questions for the corresponding topics.

Related

- [Where should I ask a question about modding Minecraft?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354760/289691)

Comment: I am not programming anything. I am just sticking image files into a folder.

Also, forge and fabric are for Java edition. I'm doing bedrock edtion.

Comment: Also, bedrock edition does not require any coding at all

Comment: @Jmooroof: json = JavaScript object notation syntax. If you are editing a manifest.json file, in a broad sense, you are coding / programming